# How to avoid getting 500 error when using Component.InvokeAsync method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use a view component in my layout but when I putting below code in my layout

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("LastNotifications");
```

I'm getting this error: 
[image]

LastNotifications is the correct value that I passed to the Invoke method and the compiler doesn't throw any error for detecting issues.

this is the last notification view component class that I have:

```
 public class LastNotificationsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

        private readonly INotificationQueries _notificationQueries;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        public LastNotificationsViewComponent(INotificationQueries notificationQueries, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _notificationQueries = notificationQueries;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var currentUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            var model = await _notificationQueries.GetMyLastNotification(currentUser.Id);
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How should we know if you don't post the exception in your question? 500 = Internal server error, always happens when an exception is not caught

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to the wrong folder location of the View component page.

Please check if your `view Components path` is correct.

View search path has three ways as following:

- /Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View
        Name}
- /Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
- /Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#creating-a-view-component).